# Photoshop, how to draw a double line

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, photoshop-cs5

I want to draw two lines next to each other (or one black line with white in the center)
This line will be very curvy and wind around on the page.
Does anyone know if this is possible in Photoshop? I'm considering upgrading to the subscription newest version.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28514/how-can-i-make-a-double-stroke-in-photoshop

Comment: If it's a curved line that winds around the page, any process that draws a line and then copies and pastes it offset a little will result in the second line always offset in one direction, so it will cross the first line.  Is that what you're looking for, or do you want something concentric (the second line always either inside or outside the first line)?

Answer (score 0):

I just drew a squiggly line with fuzzy edges, then duplicated the layer, then used paintbucket at 166 with black to make the line larger and solid. 
Then I went to the duplicated layer and used the magic wand tool to select & delete the fuzziness of the line, then I painted the line white, and VOILA!
But maybe there's an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

use can use line tool in Photoshop

1. Check the Tools on left hand side for the Line Tool.
2. Simple click and drag the line tool and the shortcut is the U key.
3. Draw parallel line

Answer (score 0):

You could find a paint brush which does this.

You could draw the line, duplicate the layer and edit as needed.

You could simply copy and paste the line

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue, and I don't see the answer to what I think your problem is, i.e. being able to draw a line that has another line offset from it whatever shape you draw. Copy/paste of the line won't work, as curves won't have a consistent offset, and may even overlap each other.

The way to do this is to create a custom brush.

Make a new small image. Make a hard black dot the diameter you want your main line to be.
Make a second black dot directly below it.
Select your dots by just using 'select all' and then using the magic wand tool with the 'subtract selection' option.
Go to 'edit', then 'define brush presets'. Save your brush.
At the moment it's just two dots. To make it work as two lines, when you select the brush, go to 'brush settings', then 'shape dynamics'.
There is an option for 'angle jitter'. You need to set this to 'direction'.

Now, whenever you draw with that brush, on those settings, you will draw two lines next to each other. Move the brush up, and there will be two adjacent lines. Move it left/right, there will be two lines, one above the other. Move it in a circle, and you'll have another circle inside your circle.

As a side note, I use this for drawing coastlines on dungeons and dragons maps.
If you make the lower dot smaller when you begin creating the brush, you will have a thick line with a thin line next to it. You can also use the same technique to create a brush with adjacent multiple lines, giving the effect of a shoreline on a map.